# How does the Peer connect to the Storage?

Tags: datomic

How does a datomic Peer (such as the console) connect to the Storage? Surely this is dependent on what storage is used. So for a SQL storage the peer will need the JDBC string and the Postgres will need to be listening on another open port (as well as the transactor). None of the examples I have seen show this.

Really not getting the whole architecture of Datomic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datomic peers connect directly to storage and also look up the transactor endpoint in storage in order to connect to the transactor. You can connect using either the URI or (with some storages) e.g. a connection map with cluster info (e.g. Cassandra) or `DataSource` (SQL storages). Options are documented in the `connect` [API docs](http://docs.datomic.com/clojure/#datomic.api/connect).